# Проверка ИМЕНИ регулярным выражением [php]

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть поле Имя: Максим
Какое регулярное выражение должно быть что бы имя было: ТОЛЬКО из английских или ТОЛЬКО из русских? без пробелов,символов и т.п.! Заранее огромное спасибо!!

Comment: вопрос вааще непонятен если честно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, например, такое:

```
  /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/ui
```

Comment: А где буква **Ё**? И оператор **i** в данном случае не имеет смысла ставить. Вот так правильно:
`/^[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ]+$/u`

Answer (score 9):

В вопросе написано с учетом "ИЛИ" (что бы быть точным):

Примерно вот такой код:

> /^[а-яА-Я]{30}|[a-zA-Z]{30}$/

Answer (score 4):

```
/^[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ]+$/u
```

Добавил букву «Ё», убрал регистронезависимость (i), так как здесь прописаны заглавные символы и строчные. Лучше потом преобразовать имя через строковые функции. Первую букву сделать заглавной, остальные — строчными.

Answer (score 3):

**Почему-то все забыли про букву "Ё", которая не входит в диапазон "А-Я" и её нужно указывать отдельно!**

Самый простой вариант. Пропускает буквы русского и латинского алфавита, без учёта регистра и ограничения кол-ва символов):

```
/^[а-яёa-z]+$/iu
```

тут разделяем алфавиты и ограничиваем символы:

```
/^[а-яё]{30}|[a-z]{30}$/iu
```

или более строгий вариант в котором первая буква строки должна быть в верхнем регистре, а все остальные в нижнем:

```
/^([А-ЯЁ]{1}[а-яё]{29})|([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{29})$/u
```

Comment: Лайк за первую заглавную, но не всегда все остальные должны быть в нижнем регистре, например MacDonald

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой вариант для полных имён типа "Иван Иванов-Суханов" или "Ivan Ivanov-Sukhanov", естественно только на одном из языков. Бонусом можно писать украинские имена:

```
/^(([a-zA-Z' -]{1,80})|([а-яА-ЯЁёІіЇїҐґЄє' -]{1,80}))$/u
```

Comment: > *ТОЛЬКО из английских или ТОЛЬКО из русских? без пробелов,символов и т.п*

Comment: Ну если в моей регулярке убрать `' ` , ну и максимальную длину поменьше поставить `{1,30}`, то получится то, что надо: `/^(([a-zA-Z-]{1,30})|([а-яА-ЯЁёІіЇїҐґЄє-]{1,30}))$/u`
Просто у меня эта регулярка работает для полных имен и пример я привел.

Comment: Дефис оставил сознательно, так как часто бывают составные имена.